# Override React Component

Tags: css, reactjs, npm, overriding, web-component

I have a react component that is being created by a NPM package. I want to alter one of the CSS properties of this component without touching any of the code in this package. In other words, I need a way to inject this CSS property into the component. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A few ideas:

1st- Depending on the NPM Module you may be able to pass a special class to the component.

2nd- Try adding a class to the component after rendering.

3rd- If you can, wrap the component in a div or span with your own class name.  This can help by allowing you granularity on your CSS Selector.

Comment: I wrapped my component in a div tag and did inline CSS styling. It worked thank you.